# How we can Html5 canvas drawing write in html file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I want make a drag and drop html UI, for that I search on google and I find html5 DnD api and canvas which is used for draw elements. But I don't know how I can save canvas drawing in html file (only canvas elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can use toDataURL() property of canvas object to save canvas contents in an DataURL that defaults to PNG format.

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("YourCanvasID");
var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var x = 75;
var y = 50;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300;
var dragok = false;

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 return setInterval(draw, 20);
}

function draw() {
 clear();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
 rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
 rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
}

function myMove(e){
 if (dragok){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
 }
}

function myDown(e){
 if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
 canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
 e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop){
  x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  dragok = true;
  canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
 }
}

function myUp(){
 dragok = false;
 canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

init();
canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Canvas Drag and Drop Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>

<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>


</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we copy a html element and drop it on canvas , Is that possible ?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.